# When should I execute unit tests and integration tests in a Dockerfile with Flask installed?

Tags: unit-testing, docker, integration-testing

I set up a new Flask Python server and I created a Dockerfile with all my codes. I've written some unit tests and I'm executing them locally. When should I execute them if I want to implement a CI/CD?

I also need to write integration tests (to test if I'm querying the database correctly, to understand if the endpoint is exposed correctly, and so on), when should I execute them in a CI/CD?

I was thinking to execute them during the `docker build` so to put the execution of the tests in the Dockerfile. Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unit tests:** Outside of Docker, before you run your `docker build`.  Within your CI pipeline, after checking out the source code and running any setup steps like installing package dependencies.

**Integration tests:** Launched from outside of Docker; depending on how complex your setup is, either late in your CI pipeline or as part of your CD pipeline.

This assumes a true "unit test" that has no external dependencies; it depends only on the application/library code, and where it needs things like databases, it either mocks out those dependencies or uses something like an embedded SQLite.  (Some frameworks are especially bad at this workflow and make it impossible to start up the application at all if the database isn't available.  But Rails doesn't run on Python.)

Running unit tests in a Dockerfile will last until it's midnight, you have a production outage, and either your quick fix that will bring the site back up happens to break one obscure unit test, or you can't wait the 5-minute cycle time to run the whole unit-test suite.  Since there shouldn't be dependencies on the Docker-or-not environment in your unit tests, I'd just run them outside Docker.

Often you can stand up enough infrastructure to be able to run your application "for real" with a couple of `docker run` commands or a simple Docker Compose setup.  In that case, it makes sense to run an integration test towards the end of your CI pipeline.  With a more complex setup (maybe one involving Kubernetes) you might need to actually deploy into a test environment, and if you have separate CI and CD tools, this would turn into "test deploy", "integration test", "pre-production deploy".

As a developer I find having tools not-in-Docker vastly easier to manage than tools that only run in Docker.  (I don't subscribe to the "any binary other than `/usr/bin/docker` is bad" philosophy.)  I'd rather just run `pytest` or `curl` than remember the 4-line `docker run` invocation to do some specific task.